# normal distribution, mean = 80 and standard deviation = 5. score? separates the top 10% of the scores from the lowest 90% of the scores

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Checking my work:
M = 80
SD = 5
X = ?
scored 90% better than others.
Closest area from table was .8997 giving a z-score of 1.28.

using the formula z = (x - M)/SD, my answer is 86.4

Comment: Seems to be good! The $z$-value is correct as I calculated with PARI/GP and you also normalized the variable.

Comment: I agree it seems right (+1). You used the normal table properly. In R statistical software: The statement `qnorm(.9, 80, 5)` returns  86.40776.